# Inheritance without default constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Since the inherited class has no default constructor, I explicitly call the inherited class's constructor, and I still got the red-underline(in VScode) at   `B`'s constructor:

> no default constructor exists for class "A"

Does class `A` have to obtain default constructor? Is there any way to fix this?

This is simplified code:

```
class A 
{
    public:
        int a_;

        A(int a): a_(a)
        {}
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
        A A1;
        A A2;

        B(int a1, int a2): A1(a1), A2(a2)
        {}
};
```

Comment: The constructor initialiser list for `B` also needs to initialise the base-class `A`.   For example, `B(int a1, int a2) : A(42), A1(a1), A2(a2) {}`.   If the inherited `A` is not listed, the the compiler tries to construct it using the "default constructor" that accepts no arguments - which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the comment, as yours is the same as Nikos C's answer, I just replied there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is about `A` not having a default constructor. Because it doesn't, there's no way to initialize the `A` part of `B`. You need something like:

```
B(int a, int a1, int a2): A(a), A1(a1), A2(a2)
{}
```

Comment: So just feed `A()` with any reasonable type of parameter, like `A(a)` in your case, then the inheritance is valid? I am kind of translating python code into c++. In the python version,  the `__init__` of class `A` doesn't have all parameters initialized with default values, but still the functions of class `A` are inherited into class `B`

Comment: @XJY95 In Python, what would be the value of `B.a_` when you instantiate a `B`?

Comment: `a1` and `a2` for `A1` and `A2`

Comment: @XJY95 `a_`, not `A1` and `A2`. `a_` has to have a value too. What would that be?

Comment: Yeah in the specific code is `a1`, I didn't look close enough into the code, thank you!

Comment: Also may I ask, is this code structure normal in C++? Or is there a better way existing?

Comment: @XJY95 No, that's perfectly normal. If your intent is for `B` to be an `A` but with two `A` members, then that's exactly how you do it.